# Rails clear flash notice after JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using Angular to send JSON request to the controller, in my controller I flash notice like this:

```
flash[:notice] = "Toon has been tagged"
```

After I want to use my rabl template to return JSON response and also include my flash notice content like this:

```
object @toon
attributes :id, :uuid, :get_tag_string
if flash
  node(:flash) do |f|
    flash.each do |k, v|
       { :msg => v, :name => k }
    end
  end
end
attributes :errors
```

My angular code handles the response and display the flash notice contents correctly. But here comes the problem, when the page refreshed the flash message is displayed again because of following code in my layout view:

```
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span8 offset1"><%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key} center")%></div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

I could remove this or do an after_filter in my controller to call flash.clear
IS THERE A BETTER WAY TO DO THIS?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve with flash.now in my controller :)

Thanks for your answer Arthur Frankel, liked your way to hand the messages

Answer (score 1):

I too am using angularjs with rails.  The way I am handling error messages from the server (rails) is to use angular route changing events. Since you are dealing with flash messages from the server, it's really the same concept.

In my angular app where I display errors (in your case flash messages) I use an ng-show with a variable, e.g.,

```
<div ng-show="showMessages" class="alert">
  {{myMessages}} // obviously here you may have an ng-repeat or similar
</div>
```

In my main angular controller I am setting $scope.showMessages (either true or false). At this point it's the same issue. In my controller I use the following callback to see when the route has changed.  When it's changed I can set $scope.showMessages to false.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
   $scope.showMessages = false;
}
```

I also use this routeChangeStart event to deal with times where I want the message to come out on the next page- by adding another var to control the "show this on the next page only".

I personally wouldn't go back to the server to clear the flash messages - that seems "expensive" whereas you wouldn't be forced to make that extra round trip.